# Common export format between OpenGL and scene kit

Tags: opengl-es, scenekit

I have successfully created a SceneKit project and i am able to export (save) the scene to a .scn file. I am able to load this .scn file.

I have another project which works on OpenGL ES. I would like to load my .scn file into this OpenGL es project. OpenGL seems to not be compatible with .scn files but is there a way to import/export data which will be compatible with both OpenGL and scene kit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SCNRenderer` will allow you to use your SceneKit model and code in your GL ES project.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnrenderer

The [Model I/O framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio) may be of use to you as well. An `MDLAsset` can be created from a SceneKit scene, saved to file, and then loaded in an Open GL project. See `MDLAsset(SCNScene: scene)`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL just draws points, lines or triangles. There's not concept of "scenes" in OpenGL per-se. It's up to the programmer to provide the program logic that implements "scenes" and uses OpenGL to draw them.

If you can provide a parser and implementation for SceneKit scenes that are backed by OpenGL you have what you want. Unfortunately I don't know of any ready to use library for that.

Comment: I am working with geometry objects in scene kit (triangle primitive), so i have vertices and indice arrays. Is there an export format in OpenGL ? I can try to write my own export in scene kit

Comment: @Bob5421: As I already wrote, OpenGL just *draws* things and you, the programmer is telling it what to draw, in what order. OpenGL does not deal with files, file formats and any of that gunk. For you it comes down to write a parser that can read whatever your exporter produces (you can stretch your wings and your imagination there, the sky is the limit) that ultimately lays down the vertices and indices in a bunch of memory regions, tells OpenGL to fetch the data from there and do glDraw… calls.